# double-decker weight and winter snow at the door

Tags: door-frame

I'm going to put a sliding patio door on my house..... 72 in. x 80 in. ,....... I will be opening the wall with the measurements of the door and I will use a two by six beam (in red) at the top.....I would like to know if this is enough to support two floors above and the winter snow.......How much does a 2x6 header weigh can handle?

[image]

Comment: Wrong order of operations. First determine the loading, THEN choose the size of the header to support that loading. If need be, hire competent licensed professional engineering help. Because you will be betting your house on it.